# HttpHandler session only works at the first request

Tags: c#, ajax, httphandler

i am using HTTP Handler to process all AJAX requests, the request works great after logging in but it only works one time, then when i call the same url again the session becomes null, any help ?

Comment: Your authentication session or the intrinsic Session[] object or the text of the response is null?

Comment: @MatthewMartin thanks Mathew, the problem was context.current.session, i used context.session and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this, the cause of the problem is that i was using context.current.session instead of just using context.session within ProcessRequest method, i don't know why but this worked !